# calling C++ method from C code

Tags: c++, c

I've read the following article [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) that explain how to call c++ based functions from pure C code.

The method is best explained with the following example :

```
// C++ code:
class C {
    // ...
    virtual double f(int);
};
extern "C" double call_C_f(C* p, int i) // wrapper function
{
    return p->f(i);
}
```

---

```
/* C code: */
double call_C_f(struct C* p, int i);
void ccc(struct C* p, int i)
{
    double d = call_C_f(p,i);
    /* ... */
}
```

---

However, I fail to understand if where do i define an instance that is pointed by 'p'. notice that in the C code, it is delivered as pointer to opaque struct, and in the C++ code it's assumed to be pointer to valid instance of `class C`, but i didn't see where this pointer is being initialized.

p.s. 
Of course that each code block that relate to different language is compiled with an appropriate compiler, and different object file is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need similar wrapper methods to create and destroy the C++ object.

C++ code:

```
extern "C" C * create_c()
{
    return new C;
}

extern "C" void destroy_c(C *p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

---

C code:

```
// forward declarations (better to put those in a header file)
struct C;
struct C * create_c();
double call_C_f(struct C* p, int i);
void destroy_c(struct C *p);

struct C * p = create_c();
double result = call_C_f(p, i);
destroy_c(p);
p = NULL;
```

Comment: A nice add-on to this answer would be a paragraph about [POD types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) since the fact that the C class has a virtual member function (preventing it from being a POD) is the real reason behind the need for an opaque struct.

Comment: thanks for the help. but in the Usage part, shouldn't i need to have function definition prior to calling. the definition is from type  'C * create_c()' ... but the C part doesn't recognize class C.

Comment: @Zohar81 just add `struct C;` to declare it

Comment: @Bryan - might want to emphasise the fact that the C code can see a declaration, but should not see a definition of `struct C` - only the C++ code should.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of your example, `p` is an object of your class `C`. You would have to create it in C++ code, and than pass it to C.

You should also declare the pointers to your C++ class as `void *` in C. The type is unknown, and `struct C` implies it's a known struct, which is wrong.

Example:

```
extern "C" {
struct C;
struct C *create_c(void)
{
     return new C;
}

void destroy_c(struct C *ptr)
{
    delete ((C*)ptr);
}
}
```

Comment: @BryanChen It does work, that's not an issue. It just gives the wrong impression, that you actually know the type in the C code. Which you don't. It's an opaque type you don't know, hence the semantic is wrong, and `void *` has the correct semantic.

Comment: I find the use of a struct useful actually. As all void pointers are equal, while different struct pointers are not.

Comment: Opaque pointer means it is a pointer to some unknown type, which is a good use here. `void *` will just make the code unmaintainable/unreadable.

Comment: If only using `void *` and if you have several types wrapped, you won't get any warning if using the wrong type because all you have will be `void *`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom All pointers are equal in C. C doesn't have type safety, `void *` and `struct C*` are equal (except that using `struct C*` will emit a `-Wvisibility` warning.

Comment: @jdarthenay You don't get a warning anyway, `void *` and `struct C*` are equal. C is **not** C++.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Incompatible pointer types will emit a warning on most modern compilers, forgot about that.

Comment: any pointer type can cast to `void *` without warning. _But_ `struct C*` is not same as `struct B*`.  C _does_ have type safety.

Comment: C does not have type safety. Your C compiler might emit a warning, but it doesn't have to. And there is no way to teach C type safety. My former example compiled just fine on C, without any warnings. In C++ it didn't.

Comment: True, you are formally correct and I used a not formally correct statement. We all know that from a standard POV "*A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type*" but, in practice, most compilers raise warnings appropriately. And that's why it's better to avoid `void*`, even if it's just for a small set of compilers. That's the point of the story and I hope you understand it. I find no work for language lawyers here.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you here. I apologize if I sounded rude.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create it in C++, most probably with `new C()`. There is no way of portably creating it in C, so in case the C code must be able to construct new instances, you'd have to write an `extern "C" C* construct_C();` factory function for it; likewise for a destructor.